# Bootstrap: how to add vertical offset in columns?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Bootstrap provides a class `col-sm-offset-*` to add spaces between columns. It is working fine on laptop screen but when we change screen resolution to mobile it displays columns arranged one below another without space.

Is there any class in bootstrap lib using which we can achieve expected result.

[Refer fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rishi24/q22xnmf9/)

Current output,

[image]

Expected result,

[image]

Comment: Currently no vertical offset is available as standard in Bootstrap 3. Adds a vertical offset top and bottom to Bootstrap 3 to be used within columns

Comment: for your code add css  ".col-sm-offset-1{ margin-top: 1em;}" [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ramachandra/q22xnmf9/1/)

Comment: You need to use margin-top property, there no other option to set vertical offset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add extra class (any name) to that particular div and use given css to it.

```css
.custom{
  margin-bottom:10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-1 custom" style="background-color:lavender;">col-1</div>
  <div class="col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-1 custom" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">col-2</div>
  <div class="col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-1 custom" style="background-color:lavender;">col-3</div>
  <div class="col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-1 custom" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">col-4</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is the best I can do as there is no class available to set vertical offset.

Answer (score 3):

A little late but a while ago i came across this:

https://gist.github.com/erobert17/9139147

which has a sass styles for vertical offsets:

```
@for $i from 0 through 12 {
  .vert-offset-top-#{$i} {
    margin-top: #{$i}em;
  }

  .vert-offset-bottom-#{$i} {
    margin-bottom: #{$i}em;
  }
}
```

It has worked pretty well for me:)

Answer (score 1):

try like this

```css
.col-sm-offset-1{
    margin-top: 1em;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-1" style="background-color:lavender;">col-1</div>
  <div class="col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-1" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">col-2</div>
  <div class="col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-1" style="background-color:lavender;">col-3</div>
  <div class="col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-1" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">col-4</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but this will add unnecessary margin-top for first row. And in big screen resolution as well.
Even I tried using - https://gist.github.com/erobert17/9139147

I guess I have to use media query then.